# Dynamically Alter HTML Source

Tags: python, html, firebug, web-scraping

I am curious if there might be a way to dynamically alter source from a web page automatically.

For instance, I know the firebug plugin for Firefox allows the capability to modify the source and see the reaction in real-time. So, say I want to login to a particular form. Could I alter this dynamic source with a login name and password and enter the website in question via some automated script? If not, are there any potential alternatives to this approach that may fair better?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, jQuery and AJAX calls can do it.  I don't know what you're thinking when you say "automated script".

Comment: Say I want to automatically login to some website using some automated Python script. I'm unable to do so because the form is Javascript, and the specific libraries such as mechanize do not play well with embedded Javascript. 

One of my thoughts were to alter the source to feed the form a username and password to login. Does this clarify at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something which can automate IE browser, what I can recommend to you is: [Watir](http://watir.com/) and [WatiN](http://watin.org/). Watir is developed in ruby while WatiN is developed in c#. They are both quite powerful, more than enough to meet your requirements.

If you have to use Python script. then I would recommend C# + WatiN + IronPython. You can write python scripts to call WatiN's dll. Please note that, IronPython is not the same as Python, it is based on microsoft's .net framework. Currently I don't know any pure python product which can do the same as WatiN and Watir.

Comment: Selenium does the same thing and has a client API for a number of languages including Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to login to a website automatically you don't need to edit the source, you need to interact with the webserver. Try [curl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) and use it to submit login details and fetch the resulting web page.

Comment: I've considered using cURL, however it doesn't seem to play nice with embedded javascript. For instance, if I want to create some Python script to automatically login, if the form is written in Javascript it doesn't seem to play nice.

Comment: In that case you might want to try [Greasemonkey scripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)

Answer (score 1):

for firefox automation, I recommend [chickenfoot](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/) to you. It can meet your needs:

> alter this dynamic source with a login
>   name and password and enter the
>   website in question via some automated
>   script

But chechenfoot only supports up to firefox 3. If you want to support the newest version of firefox, you might have to get the [source code](https://github.com/bolinfest/chickenfoot) and compile it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Javascript, try:

```
document.write("HTML CODE HERE");
```

But if you need in Python, I think you can use **REPLACE** in the HTML Source Code.

Comment: Hi Bruno. I appreciate the intent, but I don't believe your method will work. Just simply replacing the source is not enough, I would still have to get the server to recognize these changes. Unless there is some way that I am unaware of.