# parse and answer questions

Tags: python, html, parsing, automation

Lets say I have a question named Q1 with 4 radio answers:

```
Q1:
a)
b)
c)
d)
```

In python, how would you go about finding the question and then selecting one of four of the answers, then submitting the webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) would work well in this situation. Here are some examples to get you started :

http://twill.idyll.org/examples.html

You may or may not want to use twill in tandem with Beautiful Soup

Answer (score 0):

You might want to automate the browser, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560678/dynamically-alter-html-source/6560747#6560747)